# UPDATE statement for updating certain row in MySQL database using C#

Tags: c#, mysql, workbench

I have ID in my database set as primary key for every table and I'm not sure how to write code for updating certain row in table "clan" in my C# Windows Form application.

I previously had code that was vulnerable to SQL Injection which also didn't update table but I discarded that code and changed it.

This is code which I'm trying to update certain table with. 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/lVPLc.jpg Here you can see my application design and table creation.

```
        try
        {
            connection = new MySqlConnection();
            connection.ConnectionString = conString;
            connection.Open();


            string Query="UPDATE clan SET ime=@ime, prezime=@prezime, dob=@dob, oib=@oib";

            using (MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(Query, connection))
                {
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ime", ime);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@prezime", prezime);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dob", datum_rodenja);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@oib", oib);

                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }

                MessageBox.Show("Uspješno ažuriran član!");

                DialogResult dialogResult = MessageBox.Show(" Želite li ažurirati još jednog člana? ", "", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
                if (dialogResult == DialogResult.Yes)
                {
                    this.Focus();
                }
                else
                {
                    this.Close();
                }
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Just add a `where` clause to the SQL statement: `UPDATE clan SET ime=@ime, prezime=@prezime, dob=@dob, oib=@oib WHERE id = @id`

Comment: @haldo I added that but it gives me fatal error encountered during command execution. I don't know how to make my app use id (primary key, not null, unique index and auto increment all marked in table) to know what member to update.

Comment: @madreflection That's a gracious response; I'll delete my comment too. I've seen similar comments posted often enough that I've considered writing a post about it. At the end of the day, MySQL's text protocol is just strings on the wire. No matter how you type your parameter values in code, they just get sent as `123,'abc'` etc. anyway, then the server parses them and checks them against the column type. Unlike SQL Server, no "type" information is sent on the wire, so setting a parameter type is fairly pointless and `AddWithValue` is the most efficient approach.

Comment: Do you have the id of the row you wish to update David? If so use @haldo's code ensuring you add an extra parameter `command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id);`

Comment: @BradleyGrainger: I think the wire representation aspect of that article is a red herring. The real problem with `AddWithValue` (at least with the Sql provider) is in how it *detects* the data type (including length) within the provider objects (pre-wire). Reusing a command and its arguments to repeat a command with different values is a valid use case where that can go very wrong if the first value is shorter than the ones that come after it.

Comment: @SimonWilson I updated my Query with WHERE id=@id and added a command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id) but it says that 'id' does not exist in the current context. And I believe this is the root of my problem, since I'm not letting user to enter his own id, only the name, surname, etc. and I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: @BradleyGrainger: Allow me to nudge you toward writing that article. The more technically accurate information available, particularly related to the differences between RDBMS systems and their ADO.NET providers, the better.

Comment: @madreflection I've (finally) posted a simple first version of that article: https://mysqlconnector.net/overview/using-addwithvalue/